# How to display objects like arrows directly on the screen

Tags: python

Is it possible in Python to draw objects (arrows, rectangles etc. of a specific color) directly on the screen (there should be possibility to click underneath this objects)?

EDIT: I meant printing objects **DIRECTLY on the screen**, not in separate windows, like below (blue arrow on desktop)

[image]

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python draw objects", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I clarified my question after edit.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [TkInter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html), which is the standard GUI library within Python.

A [Hello, World! example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program) is provided in the documentation.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Of course, there are many other GUI libraries for Python (e.g. https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) for more specific or advanced purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to draw in tkinter objects like blue arrow on the photo (in my edited post)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `print` statement.

```
>>>print("-->")
-->
>>>print(" ___\n|__|")
___
|__|
```